# Factory for classes unknown at compile time

Tags: java, design-patterns, beginner, generics

I have a class called `Machine`. It contains a list of parts and a list of actions. The list of parts will contain instances of the `Part` class subclasses and the list of actions will contain instances of my `Action` class subclasses. Each `Part` subclass will have its corresponding `Action` subclass. None of the subclasses are available at compile time. When a `Machine` instance starts all its parts should perform their action.

An action will perform the same manipulation for each `Part` subclass so I am trying to create a factory class that will create a single instance for each `Action` subclass. My first thought was to use an interface for `Action`, but then I would have to create an `Action` instance for each `Part` instance I create, or make each class that implemented `Action` responsible for making itself a singleton. I am not sure if a factory is the best solution and if I am implementing the pattern correctly.

Neither `Action` nor `Part` subclasses are available to me so I am using generics. I am new to Java so I am not sure if I am using them correctly - Eclipse gives me several Raw type warnings (I indicated where). Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GenericsTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException,
            IllegalAccessException
    {

        ArrayList<Part> parts = new ArrayList<Part>();

        Rotate rotate = ActionFactory.getAction(Rotate.class);
        Move move = ActionFactory.getAction(Move.class);

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Gear gear = new Gear();
            gear.value1 = i;
            gear.actions.add(rotate);
            parts.add(gear);

            Lever lever = new Lever();
            lever.value2 = i + 2000;
            lever.actions.add(move);
            parts.add(lever);
        }

        Machine machine = new Machine();
        machine.parts.addAll(parts);
        machine.start();
    }

}

class Machine
{
    public void start()
    {
        for (Part part : parts)
        {
            // Raw type warning
            for (Action action : part.actions)
            {
                // Raw type warning
                action.execute(part);
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Part> parts = new ArrayList<Part>();
}

abstract class Part
{
    // Raw type warning
    public ArrayList<Action> actions = new ArrayList<Action>();
}

abstract class Action<T extends Part>
{
    abstract public void execute(T part);
}

class ActionFactory<T extends Action>
{

    public static <T> T getAction(Class<T> c) throws InstantiationException,
            IllegalAccessException
    {
        T returnAction = null;

        for (Action action : actions)
        {
            if (action.getClass() == c)
            {
                // Unchecked cast warning
                returnAction = (T) action;
            }
        }

        if (returnAction == null)
        {
            returnAction = c.newInstance();
            actions.add((Action) returnAction);
        }

        return returnAction;
    }

    private static ArrayList<Action> actions = new ArrayList<Action>();
}

/*
 * Subject1, Subject2, Action1 and Action2, somewhere else:
 */

class Gear extends Part
{
    public int value1;
}

class Lever extends Part
{
    public int value2;
}

class Rotate extends Action<Gear>
{

    @Override
    public void execute(Gear part)
    {
        System.out.println("rotate action executed, value 1: " + part.value1);
    }
}

class Move extends Action<Lever>
{

    @Override
    public void execute(Lever part)
    {
        System.out.println("move action executed, value 2: " + part.value2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a question. How do you know class Gear and class Lever in the GenericsTests when you said that the Gear and Lever are somewhere else?

Comment: I used Gear (and Lever) just as an example. It could be any class inherited from Part.

Comment: I really don't see how "None of the subclasses are available at compile time." To me, it looks like all your subclasses are available at compile time. What exactly do you mean here?

Comment: I would just provide the machine and the base classes or interfaces,  and other users would define  the concrete parts and actions they are able to perform, then create a machine instance add parts to it and start it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand exactly the purpose of the code but having two similar object inheritance tree (`Action`s and `Part`s) smells a little bit. It also seems a sample code and I guess it violates the single responsibility principle (the behaviour of a part is separated to two classes) and it might also violates the Liskov substitution principle too (if you have an `Action` you can't use it with any kind of `Part`). I'd consider moving the action code to the `Part` class or creating generic `Action` classes which ignore unhandled `Part`s (by class type). Anyway, it's hard to say something more useful without the purpose of the code. See also: [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29), [Parallel Inheritance Hierarchies](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ParallelInheritanceHierarchies).

Other notes:

1. `ArrayList<...>` reference types should be simply `List<...>`. See: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*

   ```
   List<Part> parts = new ArrayList<Part>();
   ```
2. Public fields usually leads to harder maintenance. See: [What's the deal with Java's public fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7959129/843804)

Some other ideas to consider:

1. Create a separate `Action` instance for every part and action. Pass the `Part` instance to the constructor of your `Action`. For example:

   ```
   Action rotate = new Rotate(gear);
   ```

   Store the actions in a list and then you can call `execute` on the `rotate` instance:

   ```
   for (final Action action: actions) {
       action.execute();
   }
   ```

   It's type-safe, clients can't create an `Action` with a wrong `Part` type.
2. I'd move the `actions` list from the `Part` object to somewhere else. Why should a part know what actions does a machine do with it? It seems to me that this responsibility should be stored somewhere else. The `Macine` is the closest object now (but it might deserve separate class).
3. If the `Action` classes do not have any state consider moving their code inside the `Part` object. (The basic idea of OOP is that the data and the logic which operates with the data should be together in a class.) You can mark the action method with an `@Action` annotation and parse it runtime.

   ```
   public class Gear {

       ...

       @Action
       public void rotate() {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

   I guess you still need a class which stores the actions which a machine should do:

   ```
   public class Action {
       private Part part;
       private String actionMethodName;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

This is a complicated setup you have, and this problem has been successfully solved in a few ways.... but, all of the mechanisms have two things in common....

1. Interfaces.
2. Factories

The three technical problems I see with your code are:

- false generics: You have the factory `class ActionFactory<T extends Action>` which implies that the factory has something to do with actions, and with a generic type called 'T'.

  This is simply not true.... The generic type on your class is completely ignored. You do not even need to create an instance of the class. The two static methods on the class have their own `T` generic type, and the `T` on those methods have absoutely nothing to do with the `T` on the class.
- even though I think the Part should be an interface, which would 'fix' this, there is no way you should have (in `Part`_ : `public ArrayList<Action> actions = new ArrayList<Action>();`. This should be a hidden (and final) field that is accessed with getters and setters:

  ```
  public void addAction(Action<? extends T> action);
  ....
  public List<Action<...>> getActions();
  ```
- The `Part` and `Action<T extends Part>` should both be interfaces.

This is a challenging problem to face. There are going to be places where the generics are wrong, right now they are off in ways that make the code very hard to understand.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this `ActionFactory` might work for you.

- The `ActionFactory` has only one method, and it is `static`, so make the constructor private to prevent the factory from being instantiated.  The `ActionFactory` itself needs no type parameters.
- The type parameter for `getAction()` should have a constraint requiring `T` to be a subclass of `Action`.  Then `actions.add(…)` would not need to cast.
- Instead of keeping an `ArrayList` of `Action`s, keep a `Map` instead for a simple lookup.
- There would still be an unchecked cast warning, which I believe is unavoidable.  Just suppress it with an annotation.

```
class ActionFactory
{
    private static final Map<Class, Action> singletons = new HashMap<Class, Action>();

    private ActionFactory() {}

    public static <T extends Action> T getAction(Class<T> c)
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T action = (T)singletons.get(c);

        if (action == null)
        {
            action = c.newInstance();
            singletons.put(c, action);
        }

        return action;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. It seems obvious now that my Part/Action code should be one class, but I'm not sure how to implement this yet. When I come up with something I'll post an new question here.