# Model simulation using Java annotations

Tags: java, design-patterns, beginner, generics, simulation

A couple of days ago I [posted my code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41725/factory-for-classes-unknown-at-compile-time) that models systems made up of moving parts. I got several great tips and ideas and here is my latest version. My actions are now methods annotated with @Action (instead of separate classes as in my original code). My `Model` class contains a `HashMap` of Class, `ArrayList<? extends Agent>` so each `ArrayList` contains agents of the same type.

In my`Model.start()` method I get annotated methods for each class and invoke them on each `ArrayList` member. The code looks more promising than the original one, but my main concern is that I had to use reflection to invoke actions on each model agent as I read that reflection is costly.

I would also like to hear your opinions on my usage of generics as I am new to the concept.

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class GenericsTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException
    {
        Model machine = new Model();

        ArrayList<Gear> gears = new ArrayList<Gear>();
        ArrayList<Lever> levers = new ArrayList<Lever>();

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Gear gear = new Gear();
            gear.setDiameter(i);
            gears.add(gear);

            Lever lever = new Lever();
            lever.setLength(i + 2000);
            levers.add(lever);
        }

        machine.addAgentList(Gear.class, gears);
        machine.addAgentList(Lever.class, levers);

        machine.start();
    }

}

class Model
{
    public void start()
    {
        for (Class<? extends Agent> clazz : listOfAgents.keySet())
        {
            List<Method> actions = new ArrayList<Method>();
            for (Method m : clazz.getDeclaredMethods())
            {
                if (m.isAnnotationPresent(Action.class))
                {
                    actions.add(m);
                }
            }

            for (Agent agent : listOfAgents.get(clazz))
            {
                for (Method action : actions)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        action.invoke(agent, new Object[]
                        {});
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException 
                            | IllegalArgumentException
                            | InvocationTargetException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Map<Class<? extends Agent>, ArrayList<? extends Agent>> getAgentLists()
    {
        return listOfAgents;
    }

    public void addAgentList(Class<? extends Agent> cls,
            ArrayList<? extends Agent> agents)
    {
        listOfAgents.put(cls, agents);
    }

    private final Map<Class<? extends Agent>, ArrayList<? extends Agent>> listOfAgents = 
            new HashMap<Class<? extends Agent>, ArrayList<? extends Agent>>();
}

interface Agent
{
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value = ElementType.METHOD)
@interface Action
{
}

/*
 * Agent classes
 */

class Gear implements Agent
{
    private int diameter;

    public int getDiameter()
    {
        return diameter;
    }

    public void setDiameter(int diameter)
    {
        this.diameter = diameter;
    }

    @Action
    public void rotate()
    {
        System.out.println("rotating ... " + this.toString() + " "
                + this.diameter);
    }

    @Action
    public void replace()
    {
        System.out.println("replacing ..." + this.toString() + " "
                + this.diameter);
    }
}

class Lever implements Agent
{
    private int length;

    public int getLength()
    {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(int length)
    {
        this.length = length;
    }

    @Action
    public void move()
    {
        System.out.println("moving ..." + this.toString() + " " + this.length);
    }
}
```

I will also try improve my original `FactoryClass` idea making `Action` an interface and post the code in another post.

**EDIT**

Changed the code to improve my list declarations:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class GenericsTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException
    {
        Model machine = new Model();

        List<Gear> gears = new ArrayList<Gear>();
        List<Lever> levers = new ArrayList<Lever>();

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Gear gear = new Gear();
            gear.setDiameter(i);
            gears.add(gear);

            Lever lever = new Lever();
            lever.setLength(i + 2000);
            levers.add(lever);
        }

        machine.addAgentList(Gear.class, gears);
        machine.addAgentList(Lever.class, levers);

        machine.start();
    }

}

class Model
{
    public void start()
    {
        for (Class<? extends Agent> clazz : listOfAgents.keySet())
        {
            List<Method> actions = new ArrayList<Method>();
            for (Method m : clazz.getDeclaredMethods())
            {
                if (m.isAnnotationPresent(Action.class))
                {
                    actions.add(m);
                }
            }

            for (Agent agent : listOfAgents.get(clazz))
            {
                for (Method action : actions)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        action.invoke(agent, new Object[]
                        {});
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException 
                            | IllegalArgumentException
                            | InvocationTargetException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Map<Class<? extends Agent>, List<? extends Agent>> getAgentLists()
    {
        return listOfAgents;
    }

    public void addAgentList(Class<? extends Agent> cls,
            List<? extends Agent> agents)
    {
        listOfAgents.put(cls, agents);
    }

    private final Map<Class<? extends Agent>, List<? extends Agent>> listOfAgents = 
            new HashMap<Class<? extends Agent>, List<? extends Agent>>();
}

interface Agent
{
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value = ElementType.METHOD)
@interface Action
{
}

/*
 * Agent classes
 */

class Gear implements Agent
{
    private int diameter;

    public int getDiameter()
    {
        return diameter;
    }

    public void setDiameter(int diameter)
    {
        this.diameter = diameter;
    }

    @Action
    public void rotate()
    {
        System.out.println("rotating ... " + this.toString() + " "
                + this.diameter);
    }

    @Action
    public void replace()
    {
        System.out.println("replacing ..." + this.toString() + " "
                + this.diameter);
    }
}

class Lever implements Agent
{
    private int length;

    public int getLength()
    {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(int length)
    {
        this.length = length;
    }

    @Action
    public void move()
    {
        System.out.println("moving ..." + this.toString() + " " + this.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Last time the accepted answer says: `ArrayList<...>` reference types should be simply `List<...>`. But you still have `ArrayList`s all over.

Comment: You are right. I have now changed my code accordingly and post it as an edit to my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. ```
   private final Map<Class<? extends Agent>, List<? extends Agent>> listOfAgents =
       new HashMap<Class<? extends Agent>, List<? extends Agent>>();
   ```

   The map creation would be readable with Java 7's diamond operator

   ```
   private final Map<Class<? extends Agent>, List<? extends Agent>> listOfAgents =
       new HashMap<>();
   ```

   or Guava's [`newHashMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#newHashMap%28%29).

   ```
   private final Map<Class<? extends Agent>, List<? extends Agent>> listOfAgents =
       newHashMap();
   ```

   (I like the `final` keyword here, I saved me from searching code which could change the reference.)
2. According to [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language , 3 - File Organization](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141855.html#1852) field declarations should be before methods. (`Model.listOfAgents`).
3. I've seen earlier the `listOfAgents` style variables but I've found `agents` or `agentList` more easier to work with. Maybe because if more than one variable starts with `listOf` it's hard to differentiate them. Hm, I've just noticed that it's actually a map. Then, the list is a little bit misleading. I think `agents` or `agentMap` could be better.
4. Instead of maps like

   ```
   Map<X, List<Y>>
   ```

   use a `Multimap`. Guava has great implementations. ([Doc](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained), [Javadoc](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap)) It's easier to read. (The same is true for new `ArrayList<Method>()`).
5. ```
   System.out.println("moving ..." + this.toString() + " " + this.length);
   ```

   You don't need `this.` here. Modern IDEs use highlighting to separate local variables from instance variables.
6. I'd rename `Method m` to `method` for better readability. If you just look at the `actions.add(m)` line you don't have to search its type to figure out what it is, it's more obvious.
7. I'd move the `isAnnotationPresent` check to a separate method with an additional check:

   ```
   private boolean isActionMethod(Method method) {
       if (!method.isAnnotationPresent(Action.class)) {
           return false;
       }
       if (method.getParameterTypes().length != 0) {
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   }
   ```

   It prevents runtime errors when the action method has parameters.
8. Extracting out another methods would increase the abstarction level of the code:

   ```
   public void start() {
       for (final Class<? extends Agent> clazz: agentMap.keySet()) {
           final List<Method> actionMethods =
               getActionMethods(clazz);

           for (final Agent agent: agentMap.get(clazz)) {
               runAgentActions(agent, actionMethods);
           }
       }
   }

   private List<Method> getActionMethods(Class<? extends Agent> clazz) {
       final List<Method> actions = new ArrayList<Method>();
       for (final Method method: clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
           if (isActionMethod(method)) {
               actions.add(method);
           }
       }
       return actions;
   }

   private void runAgentActions(Agent agent, List<Method> actionsMethods) {
       for (final Method actionMethod: actionsMethods) {
           try {
               actionMethod.invoke(agent, new Object[] {});
           } catch (IllegalAccessException |
               IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   It provides an overview in the `start` method about what it does (without the details) and you can still check them if you are interested in.
9. If you don't switch to `Multimap` iterate over `Map.entrySet()` instead of `keySet` and `get`. It's faster.

Comment: 1. I think NetBeans actually notified me of the diamond operator at one point but I forgot about it and never checked what it is. 2. Noted 3. Yes, it's an unfortunate name, it is a map of lists 4. Thanks, haven't heard of Guava before, still struggling with JDK, will check it out. 5. I use this to help me with autocompletion and delete it afterwards, left it out. Thank you for your comments, I appreciate it.